# Перемешать данные в столбцах

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, преобразование, данные

У меня есть датасет, у него есть колонка победителя и проигравшего. Как сделать так, чтобы данные в части датасета поменялись между друг другом?
Что я пытался.

```
from random import randint
switcher = data.copy()
for i in range(len(data)):
if randint(0, 100) % 2 == 1:
    data['name.win'][i], data['name.lose'][i], \
    data['country.win'][i], data['country.lose'][i], \
    data['rating.win'][i], data['rating.lose'][i], \
    data['civ.win.name'][i], data['civ.lose.name'][i] \
    = \
    switcher['name.lose'][i], switcher['name.win'][i], \
    switcher['country.lose'][i], switcher['country.win'][i], \
    switcher['rating.lose'][i], switcher['rating.win'][i], \
    switcher['civ.lose.name'][i], switcher['civ.win.name'][i]
else:
    pass
```

Датасет.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[Ссылка на блокнот.](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/17T9duoQoZvpsijT91-Jt6cONfdQ7IIcp?usp=sharing)
[Ссылка на датасет.](https://www.kaggle.com/slappdun/35000-age-of-empires-2-1v1-ranked-random-matches)

Comment: разберитесь с локатором loc и iloc - в вашем случае скорее всего подойдет последний. вы неверно указываете индексы, нужно не df[column_name][row], а df.iloc[row, column_name]. ну и потом, зачем писать сложные процедуры по отбору случайных записей, если в pandas есть функция df.sample()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

попробуйте что-то вроде этого:

```
switch = data.sample(len(data)//2)  # выборка половины датасета в случайном порядке
win = [...]  # здесь список названий колонок с win
lose = [...]  # здесь список названий колонок с lose (порядок такой же как в win)
switch[win],switch[lose] = switch[lose],switch[win]
data.loc[switch.index] = switch
```